# Extjs Why button cannot be resizable?

Tags: javascript, extjs, resizable

I write such code at app.js, why the button cannot be resizable? 
I have set the resizable: true, but it cannot work... the draggable works.
Can anyone help me? thanks

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});


Ext.application({
    views: [
        'MyButton',
        'MyTabPanel',
        'MyPanel3'
    ],
    name: 'MyApp',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            resizable: true,
            text: 'hello',
            draggable:true
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple code snippet works for me

```
Ext.application({
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            resizable: true,
            text: 'hello',
            draggable:true

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks. it seems it was bug of extjs. If use extjs 4.1, it works. if use extjs 4.2, it cannot work...